# Jquery search for text find element and click

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am trying to search for a text in the HTML page and find The Element of that text (test) and do a click event on it. So pretty much there is this (The data-id="337" changes so I can't be specific.

```
<table>
  <tr data-id="337" style="cursor: move" class="ui-sortable-handle">
    <td>
      <a href="/locations/1371/Test_Life/337" data-update="#TestLife">Test</a>
    </td>
  </tr 
</table>
```

This is inside a table

I thought this would work but it's not running

```
$("tr td:contains('test')").each(function() {
  $(this).trigger('click');
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others have pointed out, `:contains` is case sensitive. But if you don't want it to be, you can change the default by:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
      .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
```

Also, make sure your `each()` function is after the bound click event so it doesn't run before the click event is bound to the element.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2mgdg69d/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much for the respond

Answer (score 2):

In your case td doesn't contain `test` but `Test`, so write the search string as case sensitive.

```js
$(function(){
  $("tr td:contains('Test')").each(function(){
$(this).trigger('click');
   console.log($(this));
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr data-id="337" style="cursor: move" class="ui-sortable-handle">
            <td>
            <a href="/locations/1371/Test_Life/337" data-update="#TestLife">Test</a>  
            </td>
            <td>
            <a href="/locations/1373/Test_Life/337" data-update="#TestLife">test</a>  
            </td>
    </tr
        </table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

:contains is case sensitive.
try:

```
$("tr td:contains('Test')").each(function() {
  $(this).trigger('click');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("tr td a:contains('Test')").each(function() {
  $(this).trigger('click');
})
```